# ASP.NET Core with EF Core - DTO Collection mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use (POST/PUT) a DTO object with a collection of child objects from JavaScript to an ASP.NET Core (Web API) with an EF Core context as my data source.

The main DTO class is something like this (*simplified of course*):

```
public class CustomerDto {
    public int Id { get;set }
    ...
    public IList<PersonDto> SomePersons { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

What I don't really know is how to map this to the Customer entity class in a way that does not include a lot of code just for finding out which Persons had been added/updated/removed etc.

I have played around a bit with AutoMapper but it does not really seem to play nice with EF Core in this scenario (complex object structure) and collections.

After googling for some advice around this I haven't found any good resources around what a good approach would be. My questions is basically: should I redesign the JS-client to not use "complex" DTOs or is this something that "should" be handled by a mapping layer between my DTOs and Entity model or are there any other good solution that I am not aware of?

*I have been able to solve it with both AutoMapper and and by manually mapping between the objects but none of the solutions feels right and quickly become pretty complex with much boilerplate code.*

### **EDIT:**

The following article describes what I am referring to regarding AutoMapper and EF Core. Its not complicated code but I just want to know if it's the "best" way to manage this.

(Code from the article is edited to fit the code example above)

http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-mapping-instances/

```
var updatedPersons = new List<Person>();
foreach (var personDto in customerDto.SomePersons)
{
    var existingPerson = customer.SomePersons.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == pet.Id);
    // No existing person with this id, so add a new one
    if (existingPerson == null)
    {
        updatedPersons.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Person>(personDto));
    }
    // Existing person found, so map to existing instance
    else
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(personDto, existingPerson);
        updatedPersons.Add(existingPerson);
    }
}
// Set SomePersons to updated list (any removed items drop out naturally)
customer.SomePersons = updatedPersons;
```

Code above written as a generic extension method.

```
public static void MapCollection<TSourceType, TTargetType>(this IMapper mapper, Func<ICollection<TSourceType>> getSourceCollection, Func<TSourceType, TTargetType> getFromTargetCollection, Action<List<TTargetType>> setTargetCollection)
    {
        var updatedTargetObjects = new List<TTargetType>();
        foreach (var sourceObject in getSourceCollection())
        {
            TTargetType existingTargetObject = getFromTargetCollection(sourceObject);
            updatedTargetObjects.Add(existingTargetObject == null
                ? mapper.Map<TTargetType>(sourceObject)
                : mapper.Map(sourceObject, existingTargetObject));
        }
        setTargetCollection(updatedTargetObjects);
    }
```

.....

```
        _mapper.MapCollection(
            () => customerDto.SomePersons,
            dto => customer.SomePersons.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == dto.Id),
            targetCollection => customer.SomePersons = targetCollection as IList<Person>);
```

### **Edit:**

One thing I really want is to delcare the AutoMapper configuration in one place (Profile) not have to use the MapCollection() extension every time I use the mapper (or any other solution that requires complicating the mapping code).

So I created an extension method like this

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static ICollection<TTargetType> ResolveCollection<TSourceType, TTargetType>(this IMapper mapper,
        ICollection<TSourceType> sourceCollection,
        ICollection<TTargetType> targetCollection,
        Func<ICollection<TTargetType>, TSourceType, TTargetType> getMappingTargetFromTargetCollectionOrNull)
    {
        var existing = targetCollection.ToList();
        targetCollection.Clear();
        return ResolveCollection(mapper, sourceCollection, s => getMappingTargetFromTargetCollectionOrNull(existing, s), t => t);
    }

    private static ICollection<TTargetType> ResolveCollection<TSourceType, TTargetType>(
        IMapper mapper,
        ICollection<TSourceType> sourceCollection,
        Func<TSourceType, TTargetType> getMappingTargetFromTargetCollectionOrNull,
        Func<IList<TTargetType>, ICollection<TTargetType>> updateTargetCollection)
    {
        var updatedTargetObjects = new List<TTargetType>();
        foreach (var sourceObject in sourceCollection ?? Enumerable.Empty<TSourceType>())
        {
            TTargetType existingTargetObject = getMappingTargetFromTargetCollectionOrNull(sourceObject);
            updatedTargetObjects.Add(existingTargetObject == null
                ? mapper.Map<TTargetType>(sourceObject)
                : mapper.Map(sourceObject, existingTargetObject));
        }
        return updateTargetCollection(updatedTargetObjects);
    }
}
```

Then when I create the mappings I us it like this:

```
    CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>()
        .ForMember(m => m.SomePersons, o =>
        {
            o.ResolveUsing((source, target, member, ctx) =>
            {
                return ctx.Mapper.ResolveCollection(
                    source.SomePersons,
                    target.SomePersons,
                    (targetCollection, sourceObject) => targetCollection.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == sourceObject.Id));
            });
        });
```

Which allow me to use it like this when mapping:

```
_mapper.Map(customerDto, customer);
```

And the resolver takes care of the mapping.

Comment: what is the issue with `AutoMapper` ?

Comment: If you have a complex data structure, mapping it to something completely different will most often be complex. You should only have to configure the AutoMapper mappings once, however.

Comment: Mapping from Entity to DTO are pretty straight forward with AutoMapper but from DTO to EF Core managed entities becomes very complicated and tedious quite fast when having collections etc.
@Sampath It's not a direct problem with AutoMapper, it does what it suppose to do quite well but I am not sure that it´s the right tool for the job in this case.

It's not the number of times I need to configure AutoMapper it's the amount of configuration needed, but as Mike Brind stated perhaps it's a more complex problem than what I "feel" it should be.
Anyhow, cannot really find any "best practices".

Comment: how can we see your complex mapping by using above simple example ? you have to put more code here.

Comment: @Sampath you are perhaps misunderstanding what I mean, I am not talking about a specific complex mapping, I just referring to complex object graphs in general e.g. Customers with Orders with OrderLines etc. 
So it not a super complex or complicated graph that need to be mapped but just some general guidance whether AutoMapper is a good solution or if there are other better option. Perhaps AutoMapper is the best tool for the job?

Comment: I think I´ve got what you´re looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452054/asp-net-core-with-ef-core-dto-collection-mapping/57976673#57976673

Answer (score 10):

`AutoMapper` is the best solution.

You can do it very easily like this :

```cs
    Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();

    Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>();
```

**Note :** Because `AutoMapper` will automatically map the `List<Person>` to `List<PersonDto>`.since they have `same name`, and there is already a mapping from `Person` to `PersonDto`.

If you need to know how to inject it to ASP.net core,you have to see this article : [**Integrating AutoMapper with ASP.NET Core DI**](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/20/integrating-automapper-with-asp-net-core-di/)

**Auto mapping between DTOs and entities**

[**Mapping using attributes and extension methods**](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Transfer-Objects)

Comment: the problem is not the mapping code, it's pretty straightforward as you show above. But it is how it works and behaves in combination with EF Core (or other ORMs).
See my edit above for more details about what I mean.

Comment: I cannot see any problem about using `AutoMapper` with any `ORM` tool. Actually it's pretty standard thing these days.Otherwise you have to map properties one by one manually. Which is very cumbersome task.I'm using `aspnetzero` as my app development framework.On that framework `AutoMapper` is the default mapping Api. That framework provides lot of inbuilt extensions with `AutoMapper'.They have `opensource` product also.if you want to see that I can share that url with you.please let me know if you need it.this is the commercial one :https://www.aspnetzero.com/

Comment: So the code I added above is not necessary according to you or is it (or similar) what I have to do to make it work?

Comment: you can use that too.we can write any extension method based on `Automapper`,On my application we're using `attribute based` `Automapper` extensions.usage is like this : `var property = input.Property.MapTo<Property>();`.so many variations are there.but all are based on `AutoMapper`.

Comment: So when you say that you are using an attribute based extension I am really curious how it would be used for the example stated above (and mentioned in the article).
(I added an extension method for the code example above in my question)

Comment: Saying AutoMapper is the best solution, is like saying  *<specific brand of butter>* is the best butter. Using AutoMapper is probably a good solution. But you can never prove that it's the best. That aside though, AutoMapper is great, but thats' just my humble opinion.

Comment: updated.please see this section on the above article : `Mapping using attributes and extension methods`

Comment: @Sampath it's a good article describing the need for DTOs as well as a simple example of Entity->DTO mapping. Including an Attribute approach.
But it does not at all address the question I have: Mapping complex DTOs to ORM Entities. Ex: AutoMapper with EF Core (ORM) collections.
I agree with you that AutoMapper is good and that DTOs are useful, that's not the point.

Answer (score 4):

First I would recommend using [JsonPatchDocument](http://jsonpatch.com/) for your update:

```
    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<CustomerDTO> patchDocument)
    {
        var customer = context.EntityWithRelationships.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        var dto = mapper.Map<CustomerDTO>(customer);
        patchDocument.ApplyTo(dto);
        var updated = mapper.Map(dto, customer);
        context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return NoContent();
    }
```

And secound you should take advantage of [AutoMapper.Collections.EFCore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore). This is how I configured AutoMapper in `Startup.cs` with an extension method, so that I´m able to call `services.AddAutoMapper()` without the whole configuration-code:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
            cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<MyContext>(services);
            cfg.AddProfile(new YourProfile()); // <- you can do this however you like
        });
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return services.AddSingleton(mapper);
    }
```

This is what `YourProfile` should look like:

```
    public YourProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>(MemberList.Destination)
            .EqualityComparison((p, dto) => p.Id == dto.Id)
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ReverseMap();
    }
```

I have a similar object-graph an this works fine for me.

**EDIT**
I use LazyLoading, if you don´t you have to explicitly load navigationProperties/Collections.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu can you tell me how to use the approach, shown in your link with my configuration? I didn´t get this to work as expected together with the collection package.. Thank you :)

Comment: There is an `AddAutoMapper` overload that allows you to customize the config. I don't know if there is a smoother way.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the very same issue for quite some time. After digging through many articles I've came up with my own implementation which I'm sharing with you.

First of all I've created a custom `IMemberValueResolver`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace AutoMapper
{
    public class CollectionValueResolver<TDto, TItemDto, TModel, TItemModel> : IMemberValueResolver<TDto, TModel, IEnumerable<TItemDto>, IEnumerable<TItemModel>>
        where TDto : class
        where TModel : class
    {
        private readonly Func<TItemDto, TItemModel, bool> _keyMatch;
        private readonly Func<TItemDto, bool> _saveOnlyIf;

        public CollectionValueResolver(Func<TItemDto, TItemModel, bool> keyMatch, Func<TItemDto, bool> saveOnlyIf = null)
        {
            _keyMatch = keyMatch;
            _saveOnlyIf = saveOnlyIf;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TItemModel> Resolve(TDto sourceDto, TModel destinationModel, IEnumerable<TItemDto> sourceDtos, IEnumerable<TItemModel> destinationModels, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var mapper = context.Mapper;

            var models = new List<TItemModel>();
            foreach (var dto in sourceDtos)
            {
                if (_saveOnlyIf == null || _saveOnlyIf(dto))
                {
                    var existingModel = destinationModels.SingleOrDefault(model => _keyMatch(dto, model));
                    if (EqualityComparer<TItemModel>.Default.Equals(existingModel, default(TItemModel)))
                    {
                        models.Add(mapper.Map<TItemModel>(dto));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mapper.Map(dto, existingModel);
                        models.Add(existingModel);
                    }
                }
            }

            return models;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I configure AutoMapper and add my specific mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<TDto, TModel>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.DestinationCollection, opts =>
        opts.ResolveUsing(new CollectionValueResolver<TDto, TItemDto, TModel, TItemModel>((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.SomeOtherId, src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.ThisValueShouldntBeEmpty)), src => src.SourceCollection));
```

This implementation allows me to fully customize my object matching logic due to `keyMatch` function that is passed in constructor. You can also pass an additional `saveOnlyIf` function if you for some reason need to verify passed objects if they are suitable for mapping (in my case there were some objects that shouldn't be mapped and added to collection if they didn't pass an extra validation).

Then e.g. in your controller if you want to update your disconnected graph you should do the following:

```
var model = await Service.GetAsync(dto.Id); // obtain existing object from db
Mapper.Map(dto, model);
await Service.UpdateAsync(model);
```

This works for me. It's up to you if this implementation suits you better than what author of this question proposed in his edited post:)