# c# Entity Framework Update Nested with AutoMapper

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have a problem with updating nested object with .net core 1.1.
Once Automapper maps changed object to existing one I have this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
>   'Nutrition' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type
>   with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities,
>   for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no
>   key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for
>   its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities,
>   ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values
>   generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities,
>   ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
>   attached to the context.

Method:

```
public async Task<ProductDto> UpdateProduct(ProductDto productDto)
    {
      var product = await _context.Products
        .Include(x => x.Composition)
        .Include(x => x.Nutritions)
        .Include(x => x.ProductIngredient).ThenInclude(x => x.Ingredients).ThenInclude(x => x.IngredientComposition)
        .Include(x => x.ProductionProcess)
        .Where(x => x.Id == productDto.Id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
      if (!EligabilityCheck(product.CustomerId)) return null;
      await UpdateImages(productDto, product);
      _mapper.Map(productDto, product);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      return productDto;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Deleted properties are just removed from the object, updated ones still has same Ids and new ones have Id = 0

Comment: *updated ones still has same Ids* But they are new **instances** with the same Ids - exactly what the exception message is telling you. I think [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) package is addressing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Ivan Stoev, unfortunately Automapper.Collection.EntityFramework (I assume I need this package as well) isn't supported in .net core 1.1, does this mean I'd need to map it manually?

Comment: I guess so. Unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core with EF Core - DTO Collection mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452054/asp-net-core-with-ef-core-dto-collection-mapping)

Comment: My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452054/asp-net-core-with-ef-core-dto-collection-mapping/57976673#57976673 should answer your question as well