# Automapper, Entity Framework Core and multiple nested collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

My database has two tables - RuleGroups and Rules. My Entity Framework classes are the following:

```
public class RuleGroup
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RuleGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RuleGroupId")]
    public virtual RuleGroup RuleGroup { get; set; }
}

[NotMapped]
public class Condition
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Class Condition is not mapped because it is being serialized and stored as JSON in Rule Table (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829824/how-to-store-json-in-an-entity-field-with-ef-core/44830852) example)

My DTOS are the following:

```
public class UpdateRuleGroupDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UpdateRuleDto> Rules { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateRuleDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UpdateConditionDto> Conditions { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateConditionDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my Startup.cs I initialize Automapper :

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UpdateRuleGroupDto, RuleGroup>();
    cfg.CreateMap<UpdateRuleDto, Rule>();
    cfg.CreateMap<UpdateConditionDto, Condition>();
}
```

I have an API controller endpoint that accepts JSON PATCH document to make changes to data stored in database.

```
public IActionResult Patch(Guid ruleGroupId, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<UpdateRuleGroupDto> body)
{
    RuleGroup ruleGroupFromRepo = _deviceRules.GetRuleGroup(ruleGroupId);
    UpdateRuleGroupDto ruleGroupToPatch = Mapper.Map<UpdateRuleGroupDto>(ruleGroupFromRepo); 

    // Patching logic here

    Mapper.Map(ruleGroupToPatch, ruleGroupFromRepo);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return NoContent();
}
```

**The problem:**

When changes are made/saved, Rules in Rule table change their/get new GUID.

Example, say we have this data in 2 Tables.

```
  RuleGroup Table
  [Id][Name]
  [ddad5cac-e5a1-4db7-8167-66a6de3b8a0c][Test]

  Rule Table
  [Id][RuleGroupId][Name][Condition]
  [17c38ee8-4158-4ecc-b893-97786fa76e13][ddad5cac-e5a1-4db7-8167-66a6de3b8a0c][Test][[{"Name":"Test"}]]
```

If I change field [Name] to a new value, Rules Table will look like this.

```
  Rule Table
  [Id][RuleGroupId][Name][Condition]
  [ba106de8-bcbc-4170-ba56-80fe619cd757][ddad5cac-e5a1-4db7-8167-66a6de3b8a0c][Test2][[{"Name":"Test"}]]
```

Note that [Id] field has now a new GUID.

**EDIT**

@Gert Arnold made me realize that I'm not attaching entities.
I ran the following code:

```
  foreach (var item in ruleGroupFromRepo.rules)
  {
    var x = _context.Entry(item).State;
  }
```

and all the states were **Added** and not modified. Now I just have to figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: You don't show how you attach the entities to the context, but somehow the `Rule` is attached as new (`Added`).

Comment: Check https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore.

Comment: @Gert Arnold You mean context.Attach() ? I'm not using it at the moment.

Comment: Here is a solution with the package mentioned by @LucianBargaoanu : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452054/asp-net-core-with-ef-core-dto-collection-mapping/57976673#57976673