# Values selected in dropdown list of a front side are not being passed to the property of the viewmodel after submitting the post form in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown

everyone. I hope for your help.
I can't get a data from dropdown list of front side. I always have null in this properties of a viewmodel.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Add()
{
    var projectDropdown = _projectsService.GetProjectDropdowns();
    ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(projectDropdown.Users, "Id", "Fullname");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(ProjectViewModel projectVM)
{
    var projectDropdown = _projectsService.GetProjectDropdowns();
    ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(projectDropdown.Users, "Id", "Fullname");

    _projectsService.AddProject(projectVM);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public required ProjectStatus Status { get; set; }

    public User? ProjectAdmin { get; set; }

    public List<User>? Users { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProjectAdmin" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="ProjectAdmin" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Users"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectAdmin" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Users" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Users" class="form-control" multiple asp-items="ViewBag.Users"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Users" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I tried also to use this variant but it does not work too.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProjectAdmin" class="control-label"></label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.ProjectAdmin, (SelectList)ViewBag.Users, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectAdmin" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I dont know why this happens, debugging does not helps.

Comment: Perhaps they are not in a form? incomplete code leaves us with some gaps in what we are able to dicern.

Answer (score 0):

When using the [`@Html.DropDownListFor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-selectextensions-dropdownlistfor-2(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-1))))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-web-mvc-selectlistitem))-system-collections-generic-idictionary((system-string-system-object)))) helper, like in your post, the first parameter should be an expression that identifies the object containing the property to display and easiest way to make it work is using a simple type: for example, `string` or `int`.

Define the `ProjectAdmin` like

```cs
public string ProjectAdmin { get; set; }
```

And than use it like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProjectAdmin" class="control-label"></label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.ProjectAdmin, (SelectList)ViewBag.Users, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectAdmin" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

When passing the data model to the view set the `ProjectAdmin` property to value that will be displayed as selected by default. When submitting the form to the controller this property will contain a new selected value.

[image]

---

The same using the `<select>` tag helper:

```
<select name="ProjectAdmin" asp-for="@Model.ProjectAdmin" asp-items="@ViewBag.Users" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your methods didn't work, but you are right about using simply types.

Comment: @gnab: What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I tried to use your fixed select but nothing happened either.

Comment: @gnab: You should replace `public User? ProjectAdmin { get; set; }` line by `public string ProjectAdmin { get; set; }`.  But the users list should be defined like in your question: `public List<User>? Users { get; set; }`. The selected item id will be returned to controller in the `ProjectAdmin` property. See the screenshot.

Comment: @gnab: Of course, to get multiple selection you are using an array: `public string[] ProjectAdmin { get; set; }`

Comment: Tried to do, it works, values comes to controller. But I have the next question. E.g. in Project View Model I have property List<string> Users, in Project Database Model I have List<User> Users. Relation is many to many. I need to create Database Model based on View Model. It is necessary to convert strings to Users. Can i do this automatically without manual creating of UserProject entity (many to many table) and using foreach (my answer below).

Comment: @gnab: Post the new question and provide minimal code to make it clearer in details. Look at posts related to the DTO mapping, like this one: [ASP.NET Core with EF Core - DTO Collection mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39452054/6630084)

Answer (score 0):

Values selected in a dropdown list will be pass to a server side if we will use a simple representation of entity, e.g. entity id (not type of entity), in a ViewModel.

```
public List<string>? UserIds { get; set; }

public List<int>? ProjectAdminIds { get; set; }
```

But, in this case, it's neсessary to create an intermediate table explicitly for many-to-many relation for translating of entity ids to entities.

```
foreach (var userId in projectVM.UserIds)
{
    var userProject = new UserProject()
    {
        ProjectId = projectDb.Id,
        UserId = userId
    };

    _context.UserProjects.Add(userProject);
}
```